# scrapy how to repeat a duplicate request

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

when I send a request to scrape API sometimes it doesn't load properly and it returns me `-1` instead of the price.

So I put a while loop to make it repeat the request as long as I get `-1` but the spider stops after the first request because of duplicate request.

so my question is, how can I change it to process duplicate requests?

example code:

```
     is_checked = False
     while(not is_checked):
         response = yield scrapy.Request("https://api.bookscouter.com/v3/prices/sell/"+isbn+".json")            
         jsonresponse = loads(response.body)
         sellPrice = jsonresponse['data']['Prices'][0]['Price']
         if sellPrice!=-1:
             is_checked = True
             yield {'SellPrice': sellPrice}
```

bare in mind I use inline requests library but it is not relevant to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force scheduling duplicate request, set [`dont_filter=True`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) in `Request`'s constructor. In your example above, change

```
response = yield scrapy.Request("https://api.bookscouter.com/v3/prices/sell/"+isbn+".json")
```

to

```
response = yield scrapy.Request("https://api.bookscouter.com/v3/prices/sell/"+isbn+".json", dont_filter=True)
```